# Special Character issue in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, special-characters

I need to update value in one table, which is having special character.
Below is the Update Query I have Executed:

```
    UPDATE TABLE_X
        SET DISPLAY_NAME = 'AC¦', NATIVE_IDENTITY='AC¦'
        WHERE ID='idNumber'
```

Special Character "¦" is not getting updated in Oracle.

I have already tried below approaches:

1. Checked the character set being used in Oracle using below query

```
    select * from nls_database_parameters  where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

It is having "US7ASCII" Character set.

2. I have tried to see if any of the character set will help using below query

```
   SELECT CONVERT('¦ ', 'ASCII') FROM DUAL;
```

I have tried below different encoding:

- WE8MSWIN1252
- AL32UTF8
- BINARY - this one is giving error "ORA-01482: unsupported character set"

Before Changing the character set in DB i wanted to try out 'CONVERT' function from Oracle, but above mentioned character set is either returning "Block Symbol" or "QuestionMark � " Symbol.

Any idea how can I incorporate this special symbol in DB?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the character in question is not part of the [US7ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/), which it does not appear to be unless you want to replace it with the ASCII vertical bar character |, you can't validly store the character in a `VARCHAR2` column in the database.

- You can change the database character set to a character set that supports all the characters you want to represent
- You can change the data type of the column to `NVARCHAR2` assuming your national character set is UTF-16 which it would normally be.
- You can store a binary representation of the character in some character set you know in a `RAW` column and convert back from the binary representation in your application logic.

I would prefer changing the database character set but that is potentially a significant change.